# Hyperparameter Tuning k-means clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, hyperparameters

I am trying to perform hyperparameter tuning for Spatio-Temporal K-Means clustering by using it in a pipeline with a Decision Tree classifier. The idea is to use the K-Means clustering algorithm to generate cluster-distance space matrix and clustered labels, which will then be passed to the Decision Tree classifier. For hyperparameter tuning, just use parameters for the K-Means algorithm.
I am using Python 3.8 and sklearn 0.22.

The data I am interested in having 3 columns/attributes: `time`, `x`, and `y` (`x` and `y` are spatial coordinates).

The code is:

```py
class ST_KMeans():
    """
    Note that the K-means clustering algorithm is designed for Euclidean distances.
    It may stop converging with other distances when the mean is no longer a
    best estimation for the cluster 'center'.

    The 'mean' minimizes squared differences (or, squared Euclidean distance).
    If you want a different distance function, you need to replace the mean with
    an appropriate center estimation.


    Parameters:

    k:  number of clusters
    
    eps1 : float, default=0.5
        The spatial density threshold (maximum spatial distance) between 
        two points to be considered related.

    eps2 : float, default=10
        The temporal threshold (maximum temporal distance) between two 
        points to be considered related.

    metric : string default='euclidean'
        The used distance metric - more options are
        ‘braycurtis’, ‘canberra’, ‘chebyshev’, ‘cityblock’, ‘correlation’,
        ‘cosine’, ‘dice’, ‘euclidean’, ‘hamming’, ‘jaccard’, ‘jensenshannon’,
        ‘kulsinski’, ‘mahalanobis’, ‘matching’, ‘rogerstanimoto’, ‘sqeuclidean’,
        ‘russellrao’, ‘seuclidean’, ‘sokalmichener’, ‘sokalsneath’, ‘yule’.
    
    n_jobs : int or None, default=-1
        The number of processes to start; -1 means use all processors (BE AWARE)


    Attributes:
    
    labels : array, shape = [n_samples]
        Cluster labels for the data - noise is defined as -1
    """

    def __init__(self, k, eps1 = 0.5, eps2 = 10, metric = 'euclidean', n_jobs = 1):
        self.k = k
        self.eps1 = eps1
        self.eps2 = eps2
        # self.min_samples = min_samples
        self.metric = metric
        self.n_jobs = n_jobs


    def fit(self, X):
        """
        Apply the ST K-Means algorithm 
        
        X : 2D numpy array. The first attribute of the array should be time attribute
            as float. The following positions in the array are treated as spatial
            coordinates.
            The structure should look like this [[time_step1, x, y], [time_step2, x, y]..]
            
            For example 2D dataset:
            array([[0,0.45,0.43],
            [0,0.54,0.34],...])


        Returns:

        self
        """
        
        # check if input is correct
        X = check_array(X)

        # type(X)
        # numpy.ndarray

        # Check arguments for DBSCAN algo-
        if not self.eps1 > 0.0 or not self.eps2 > 0.0:
            raise ValueError('eps1, eps2, minPts must be positive')

        # Get dimensions of 'X'-
        # n - number of rows
        # m - number of attributes/columns-
        n, m = X.shape


        # Compute sqaured form Euclidean Distance Matrix for 'time' and spatial attributes-
        time_dist = squareform(pdist(X[:, 0].reshape(n, 1), metric = self.metric))
        euc_dist = squareform(pdist(X[:, 1:], metric = self.metric))

        '''
        Filter the euclidean distance matrix using time distance matrix. The code snippet gets all the
        indices of the 'time_dist' matrix in which the time distance is smaller than 'eps2'.
        Afterward, for the same indices in the euclidean distance matrix the 'eps1' is doubled which results
        in the fact that the indices are not considered during clustering - as they are bigger than 'eps1'.
        '''
        # filter 'euc_dist' matrix using 'time_dist' matrix-
        dist = np.where(time_dist <= self.eps2, euc_dist, 2 * self.eps1)


        # Initialize K-Means clustering model-
        self.kmeans_clust_model = KMeans(
            n_clusters = self.k, init = 'k-means++',
            n_init = 10, max_iter = 300,
            precompute_distances = 'auto', algorithm = 'auto')

        # Train model-
        self.kmeans_clust_model.fit(dist)


        self.labels = self.kmeans_clust_model.labels_

        self.X_transformed = self.kmeans_clust_model.fit_transform(X)

        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        # print("\nX.shape = {0}\n".format(X.shape))
        # pass
        # return self.kmeans_clust_model.fit_transform(X)
        return self.X_transformed



# Initialize ST-K-Means object-
st_kmeans_algo = ST_KMeans(
    k = 5, eps1=0.6,
    eps2=9, metric='euclidean',
    n_jobs=1
    )

# Train on a chunk of dataset-
st_kmeans_algo.fit(data.loc[:500, ['time', 'x', 'y']])

# Get clustered data points labels-
kmeans_labels = st_kmeans_algo.labels

kmeans_labels.shape
# (501,)


# Get labels for points clustered using trained model-
kmeans_transformed = st_kmeans_algo.X_transformed

kmeans_transformed.shape
# (501, 5)

dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()

dtc.fit(kmeans_transformed, kmeans_labels)

y_pred = dtc.predict(kmeans_transformed)

# Get model performance metrics-
accuracy = accuracy_score(kmeans_labels, y_pred)
precision = precision_score(kmeans_labels, y_pred, average='macro')
recall = recall_score(kmeans_labels, y_pred, average='macro')

print("\nDT model metrics are:")
print("accuracy = {0:.4f}, precision = {1:.4f} & recall = {2:.4f}\n".format(
    accuracy, precision, recall
    ))

# DT model metrics are:
# accuracy = 1.0000, precision = 1.0000 & recall = 1.0000


# Define steps of pipeline-
pipeline_steps = [
    ('st_kmeans_algo' ,ST_KMeans(k = 5, eps1=0.6, eps2=9, metric='euclidean', n_jobs=1)),
    ('dtc', DecisionTreeClassifier())
    ]

# Instantiate a pipeline-
pipeline = Pipeline(pipeline_steps)

# Train pipeline-
pipeline.fit(kmeans_transformed, kmeans_labels)
```

However the `pipeline.fit()` gives the following error:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-25-711d6dd8d926> in <module>
> ----> 1 pipeline = Pipeline(pipeline_steps)
> 
> ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in
> __init__(self, steps, memory, verbose)
>     134         self.memory = memory
>     135         self.verbose = verbose
> --> 136         self._validate_steps()
>     137 
>     138     def get_params(self, deep=True):
> 
> ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in
> _validate_steps(self)
>     179             if (not (hasattr(t, "fit") or hasattr(t, "fit_transform")) or not
>     180                     hasattr(t, "transform")):
> --> 181                 raise TypeError("All intermediate steps should be "
>     182                                 "transformers and implement fit and transform "
>     183                                 "or be the string 'passthrough' "
> 
> TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement
> fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough' '<__main__.ST_KMeans
> object at 0x7f0971db5430>' (type <class '__main__.ST_KMeans'>) doesn't
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message says it all: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit **and transform**. In your case, your class `ST_KMeans()` has to implement a `transform` function as well to be used in a pipeline. Besides, best-practice is usually to inherit from the classes `BaseEstimator` and `TransformerMixin` from the module `sklearn.base`:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin


class ST_KMeans(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def fit(self, X, y=none):
        ...
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return self.X_transformed
```

Then, you can use your class in a pipeline.

Comment: After implementing the changes you suggest, when I try to use `pipeline.fit(kmeans_transformed, kmeans_labels)', it gives me the error: "TypeError: fit() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given" ?!

Comment: Did you add `y=None` to your parameter list in the `fit` function? Your error message says the function takes only 2 positional arguments. In the answer's definition, it is however 3 (self, X and y).

Comment: Yes, I did and now the new error it gives is: "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=nan.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."

Comment: Okay, the pipeline itself is apparently fine now. The error is related to the data that is passed through your pipeline. Since you checked the shape of `kmeans_transformed` before, I suppose it is a 2D array that is passed to the pipeline, right? That means the error message is not related to the first, but the second step in the pipeline. Please check that you are returning the features to finally train your classifier in your `transform` function of `ST_KMeans`. Because it seems like it is actually returning Nan.

Comment: kmeans_transformed.shape is (501, 5), so it's a 2-D array. How do I check which features are returned from 'transform()' method of 'ST_KMeans' class?

Comment: Do I see it correctly that eventually you want to pass `self.X_transformed` to your DecisionTree? Then your `transform` can return just that. I updated the answer accordingly. Does that solve the problem?

Comment: I edited my code too. Yes, your solution works but alas, it creates a new error while I try to use GridSearchCV()! Going to open a new question for that. Thanks!